# Nagios is sending notifications for hosts with scheduled downtime

Tags: nagios, maintenance

I've got the whole Nagios configured, it's working for a while now with many many hosts and everything is OK, except the one thing I've discovered. When I schedule a downtime for a host, it's sending notifications anyway. Is it some kind of a bug? What should I check/change please?

EDIT 1:
Nagios version: 3.4.1
Notification info:

```
***** Nagios *****

Notification Type: PROBLEM
Host: XXXX
State: DOWN
Address: xx.xx.xx.xx
Info: PING CRITICAL - Packet loss = 100%

Date/Time: Mon Jul 8 14:56:15 CEST 2013
```

Comment: Which version are you using? Could you please show us the full notification message?

Comment: I've edited my question, take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to thoroughly look at your configuration and your logs - I have never seen Nagios ignoring a scheduled downtime.

[Note that there is a bug](http://tracker.nagios.org/view.php?id=338) which *might* be related here, and is fixed in versions > 3.4.1.

Comment: In my other 3 versions of Nagios there wasn't any problem with this. I found nothing about scheduling downtime in my nagios.cfg file and I don't know where else to look, what else to check.

Comment: My version is 3.4.1, so the bug could imho still be there. Do you think I should use the patch? I really don't like to mess with nagios core if there is other option, but if there isn't...

Comment: I have seen notifications during downtime, too. But as Roman says, it came down to user-caused reasons *every time*.

Comment: No, don't patch. Unless you know what it does, and you really, really need it.

Comment: @Roman: I really, really need to get downtime working. But the patch is the only mention about it.

Comment: You do realize that this patch only makes sure that Nagios won't forget about your downtimes when restarting the service? If you have to restart Nagios *that much*, I'm tempted to say you're doing something wrong.

Comment: http://www.mail-archive.com/nagios-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg38435.html I've found this discussion about similar problem I have and there is also mentioned this patch. I haven't tried restarting Nagios and check if there are saved downtimes, maybe I have this problem too, but if it helps me with my problem and if nobody can't tell me what else to do...

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution !
Go to your template.cfg file and change in the contact part :

FROM :

```
service_notification_options    w,u,c,r,f,s      ; send notifications for all service states, flapping events, and scheduled downtime events
host_notification_options       d,u,r,f,s      ; send notifications for all host states, flapping events, and scheduled downtime events
```

TO :

```
service_notification_options    w,u,c,r,f      ; send notifications for all service states, flapping events, and scheduled downtime events
host_notification_options       d,u,r,f      ; send notifications for all host states, flapping events, and scheduled downtime events
```

Remove the **"s"** there remove the mail notification from nagios for scheduled downtime event.

Comment: This is few years old and I don't have Nagios anymore so I cannot verify your answer. But if you get enough upvotes from the community, I'm going to accept your answer as correct.